# updating prior rows of dataframe conditionally upon current

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`ev`), and I would like to read it and whenever the value of the 'trig' column is 64, I need to update the value of the `critical` column that is 4 rows above, and change it to 999. I tried the code below but it does not change anything, though seems it should work.

```
for i in range(0,len(ev)):  
    if ev['trig'][i] == 64:
        ev['critical'][i-4] == 999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,  you were close:  Learn about single `"="` vs double `"=="`

```
 for i in range(0,len(ev)):  
        if ev['trig'][i] == 64:
            ev['critical'][i-4] = 999
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) by `mask` with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `False`, because after [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) you get `NaN`:

```
import pandas as pd

ev = pd.DataFrame({'trig':[1,2,3,2,4,6,8,9,64,6,7,8,6,64],
                   'critical':[4,5,6,3,5,7,8,9,0,7,6,4,3,5]})

print (ev)
    critical  trig
0          4     1
1          5     2
2          6     3
3          3     2
4          5     4
5          7     6
6          8     8
7          9     9
8          0    64
9          7     6
10         6     7
11         4     8
12         3     6
13         5    64
```

```
mask = (ev.trig == 64).shift(-4).fillna(False)
print (mask)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
Name: trig, dtype: bool
```

```
ev['critical'] = ev.critical.mask(mask, 999)
print (ev)
    critical  trig
0          4     1
1          5     2
2          6     3
3          3     2
4        999     4
5          7     6
6          8     8
7          9     9
8          0    64
9        999     6
10         6     7
11         4     8
12         3     6
13         5    64
```

EDIT:

**Timings**:

I think better is avoiding iteration in `pandas`, because in large dataframe it is very slow:

`len(df)=1400`:

```
In [66]: %timeit (jez(ev))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

In [67]: %timeit (mer(ev1))
10 loops, best of 3: 49.9 ms per loop
```

`len(df)=14k`:

```
In [59]: %timeit (jez(ev))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.49 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit (mer(ev1))
1 loop, best of 3: 501 ms per loop
```

`len(df)=140k`:

```
In [63]: %timeit (jez(ev))
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit (mer(ev1))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.32 s per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
import pandas as pd

ev = pd.DataFrame({'trig':[1,2,3,2,4,6,8,9,64,6,7,8,6,64],
                   'critical':[4,5,6,3,5,7,8,9,0,7,6,4,3,5]})

print (ev)
ev = pd.concat([ev]*100).reset_index(drop=True)
#ev = pd.concat([ev]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
#ev = pd.concat([ev]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

ev1 = ev.copy()

def jez(df):
    ev['critical'] = ev.critical.mask((ev.trig == 64).shift(-4).fillna(False), 999)
    return (ev)

def mer(df):
    for i in range(0,len(ev)):  
        if ev['trig'][i] == 64:
            ev['critical'][i-4] = 999
    return (ev)

print (jez(ev))    
print (mer(ev1))
```